# What is the best wine to use in a fondue recipe?

Tags: wine, fondue

Assuming I'm willing to pull out all the stops, what is the best wine to use in a "standard" gruyere-based fondue, [like this one](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Cheese-Fondue-231492)?

Answer (score 5):

Any white with a sufficiently high acid content. The canonical fondue wine is Fendant, which is made in the valais region out of chasselas grapes, so any chasselas (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasselas) for a long list of alternative names) will work well.

One notable alternative is a dry champagne. This will make your fondue very light and fluffy, due to the carbonation.

Comment: ...and ideally, the same wine should be served with the fondue.

Comment: According to that Wikipedia article, Fendant is just an alternative name for the Chasselas grape. Are you saying that there is a specific wine with that name?

Comment: Yes and no... If it's called Fendant, it's a bog-standard chasselas made in the Valais region. Other that the provenance, there is no difference.